# No Bluetooth Adapter found Ubuntu 16.04

Tags: drivers, 16.04, bluetooth, hp

After I updated my my ubuntu 16.04 yesterday I have not been able to turn on my bluetooth. So I went ahead and searched the net and tried to turn it on (the icon was also missing from the menu bar).

I have tried this

```
sudo apt-get install blueman bluez:i386 bluetooth
```

I have also tried this

```
sudo /etc/init.d/bluetooth start
```

and this too

```
gksudo gedit /etc/rc.local
```

and I have pasted this `rfkill unblock bluetooth` before `exit 0`.

Somehow I managed to get the bluetooth icon but I am still not able to turn on my bluetooth.

Here is the output of `lspci`

```
00:00.0 Host bridge: Intel Corporation Broadwell-U Host Bridge -OPI  (rev 09)
00:02.0 VGA compatible controller: Intel Corporation Broadwell-U       Integrated Graphics (rev 09)
00:03.0 Audio device: Intel Corporation Broadwell-U Audio Controller   (rev 09)
00:04.0 Signal processing controller: Intel Corporation Broadwell-U  Camarillo Device (rev 09)
00:14.0 USB controller: Intel Corporation Wildcat Point-LP USB xHCI Controller (rev 03)
00:16.0 Communication controller: Intel Corporation Wildcat Point-LP   MEI Controller #1 (rev 03)
00:1b.0 Audio device: Intel Corporation Wildcat Point-LP High Definition Audio Controller (rev 03)
00:1c.0 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation Wildcat Point-LP PCI Express Root Port #1 (rev e3)
00:1c.2 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation Wildcat Point-LP PCI Express Root Port #3 (rev e3)
00:1c.4 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation Wildcat Point-LP PCI Express Root Port #5 (rev e3)
00:1c.5 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation Wildcat Point-LP PCI Express Root Port #6 (rev e3)
00:1f.0 ISA bridge: Intel Corporation Wildcat Point-LP LPC Controller (rev 03)
00:1f.2 SATA controller: Intel Corporation Wildcat Point-LP SATA Controller [AHCI Mode] (rev 03)
00:1f.3 SMBus: Intel Corporation Wildcat Point-LP SMBus Controller (rev 03)
00:1f.6 Signal processing controller: Intel Corporation Wildcat Point-LP Thermal Management Controller (rev 03)
07:00.0 Ethernet controller: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd.  RTL8101/2/6E PCI Express Fast/Gigabit Ethernet controller (rev 07)
0d:00.0 Display controller: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD/ATI] Sun XT [Radeon HD 8670A/8670M/8690M / R5 M330] (rev ff)
13:00.0 Network controller: Broadcom Corporation BCM43142 802.11b/g/n (rev 01)
```

Please help me.

EDIT : 
output of `lspci -nnk | grep -A2 Network`

```
Network controller [0280]: Broadcom Corporation BCM43142 802.11b/g/n [14e4:4365] (rev 01)
Subsystem: Hewlett-Packard Company BCM43142 802.11b/g/n [103c:804a]
Kernel driver in use: wl
```

Comment: @Pilot6 This was all working fine untill I updated softwares

Comment: Since the driver needs to be built for every new kernel, you'll need to rebuild it after every kernel upgrade – unless someone creates a DKMS package for it that automates the build.

Comment: @DavidFoerster Last night when I turned on my Laptop the bluetooth was working fine but when today I turned it on again the same problem.

Comment: Did you boot to a different kernel? What's the output of `lspci -nnk | grep -A2 Network`?

Comment: @DavidFoerster No, I booted in the same kernal.
Output: 
`Network controller [0280]: Broadcom Corporation BCM43142` `802.11b/g/n [14e4:4365] (rev 01)`
`Subsystem: Hewlett-Packard Company BCM43142` `802.11b/g/n[103c:804a]`
`Kernel driver in use: wl`

Comment: Could you please [edit] your post, when you want to add information? Especially file or program output [listings](/editing-help#code) (with the help of the `{}` button in the editor toolbar) will be much more readable there; alternatively you can use a [pastie service](https://paste.ubuntu.com/) for longer listings and include the link of your pastie in your question. Overall it’s best to have everything relevant in one place. Additionally, comments may be deleted for various reasons. Thanks.

Comment: `wl` is by far not the most appropriate driver for BCM43* chipsets. Could you please consult https://askubuntu.com/questions/55868/installing-broadcom-wireless-drivers and see if that improves the situation?